# Проблема с многострочными комментариями

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне для написания кода (Python 3.6) очень нужны комментарии (т.к. код больше 500 
строк). И я решил сделать своеобразные "блоки" с помощью многострочных комментариев:

''' 0 блок '''

```
''' 0.1 блок - импорты '''

    import subprocess
    import random
```

А когда запускаю, он мне выдаёт ошибку **unexpected indent**. Подскажите кто-нибудь пожалуйста, что делать.

Возможно я что-то не знаю про комментарии, просто по интернету пошарил.

Comment: У вас отступы там, где они не нужны.

Comment: А где нужны? Просто я вообще в этом не разбираюсь, а эта вещь мне очень нужна. Мне просто надо, чтобы в notepad++ можно было сворачивать этот блок

Comment: Отступы отделяют условия, циклы, функции и т.д. Просто так их нельзя делать. В Питоне с этим строго.

Comment: Что же мне тогда делать? Просто очень неудобно перелистывать постоянно по 300 строк туда и обратно

Comment: перед `import` уберите отступы

Comment: Т.е. придётся обойтись без сворачивания кода?

Comment: Почему? Многострочные комментарии прекрасно сворачиваются, по крайней мере в PyCharm IDE. На счет нотпад не знаю

Comment: А у меня именно notepad++, и сворачивается только тогда, когда я под многострочными комментариями ставлю пробелы в коде. Так и получаются у меня блоки. Только вот не работает))

Comment: Вы хотите сворачивать именно код, не только комментарий? Не, так не получится. Если только в функцию его поместить, но импорты в функции это как-то дико совсем :)

Comment: Ладно тогда. Спасибо всем за ответы. Сам бы не разобрался

Comment: Вообще, если планируете изучать программирование, то разу ставьте IDE нормальную. Там блок импортов, как правило, можно сворачивать

Comment: Мне удобнее писать на notepad++, а потом сразу запускать и устранять ошибки.

Comment: "Что же мне тогда делать? Просто очень неудобно перелистывать постоянно по 300 строк туда и обратно" - если не удобно, разбивайте код на отдельные модули.

Answer (score 3):

советую почитать основы синтаксиса python (судя по отступам перед import)
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/sintaksis-yazyka-python.html

а также статью документирование кода в python(точно есть ответы на Ваш вопрос)
https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/dokumentirovanie-koda-v-python-pep-257.html

> Многострочные строки документации состоят из однострочной строки документации с последующей пустой строкой, а затем более подробным описанием. Первая строка может быть использована автоматическими средствами индексации, поэтому важно, чтобы она находилась на одной строке и была отделена от остальной документации пустой строкой. Первая строка может быть на той же строке, где и открывающие кавычки, или на следующей строке. Вся документация должна иметь такой же отступ, как кавычки на первой строке (см. пример ниже).
>
> Вставляйте пустую строку до и после всех строк документации (однострочных или многострочных), которые документируют класс - вообще говоря, методы класса разделены друг от друга одной пустой строкой, а строка документации должна быть смещена от первого метода пустой строкой; для симметрии, поставьте пустую строку между заголовком класса и строкой документации. Строки документации функций и методов, как правило, не имеют этого требования.

```
def complex(real=0.0, imag=0.0):
    """Form a complex number.

    Keyword arguments:
    real -- the real part (default 0.0)
    imag -- the imaginary part (default 0.0)

    """
    if imag == 0.0 and real == 0.0: return complex_zero
    ...
```